# React JS checkbox value add and remove on check uncheck

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have created dynamic checkbox  and tried to get the  display the name on check and remove on uncheck and keep the other checked item but am not able to remove the value when unchecked. also want to get the all checkbox name when checked on all select

```
    const { name, checked } = e.target;

    if (checked) {
      setSelectedValue((prevName) => new Set([...prevName, name]));
    } else {
      setSelectedValue((prevName) => new Set([...prevName]))
    }
```

Comment: When you set the value in the uncheck case, you just set the previous values again. So, it won't get removed.

Comment: thanks for reply, even i tried to set name only its now working its removing all the item even checked one.. can you pls help with code to remove only unchecked and keep checked one

Comment: What's the profit and reason of using `Set` in your case instead of `Array`? As for your case you can try `setSelectedValue((prevName) => new Set([...prevName]).delete(name))` in `else` condition